# How do I calculate load?

Tags: dungeon-world

I think I figured out that my group is doing load wrong. It’s supposed to be base plus the modifier not the total strength, correct? Want to make sure before I tell the group. I realized when my thief could carry more that a barge that something was off.

The +STR threw us off, but I think I get the notation now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Base + modifier is correct.

There's a nice little bit of DW formatting that's easy to miss: "STR" always refers to the modifier, "Strength" always refers to the score. And the same's true for CON/Constitution, WIS/Wisdom, etc.

(Note that HP is based off of *Constitution*, not *CON*.)